# Upgrade Symantec EndPoint 2011 Or Use Something Else?

Tags: anti-virus, uninstall, symantec

I have got laptop with IT edition of Symantec and it slows my computer down. It constantly bugs me about .TMP files in temporary directory thinking it is a virus. It slows down laptop.

Is it better to update software or simply install other antivirus software? Just to emphasize - the Symantec's protection is free which usually has subscription.

Answer (score 1):

In my own experience, i've had horrible issues with the regular consumer versions of symantec/norton antivirus - I'm told the corp versions are better but YMMV

Assuming you had to keep you could, presumably add the temporary directory to the folders that are exempted from realtime scanning (assuming you can). Updating would not fix anything unless your issues are due to a mis-configuration on their end.

Considering that there's good free AV options (I prefer MSSE), if for some reason your AV is slowing down your system, ditching it is worth considering.

Comment: I also have sympathy to MSSE however i did not like the time it took to delete infection. Something around 1 minute. Maybe it was different for you?

Comment: Well, i hardly ever get infections, and for me, it often catches suspect files *while* they're coming in. I think the rest of the answer is relevant, should you choose to keep the current AV. Shopping around and changing your AV should be an option, however.

Comment: What is your opinion about NOD32 and Kaspersky?

Comment: I don't run either.